# popen function: Command not found or exited with error status in C program

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-16.04, popen

I'm trying to execute external command from C program in ubuntu shell, below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int BUFSIZE = 128;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = popen("ls", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening pipe!\n");
    }

    while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    if(pclose(fp))  {
        printf("Command not found or exited with error status\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

but its throwing error: `Command not found or exited with error status`, I have installed new ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Work for me on ubuntu 18.04. gcc main.c; ./a.out

Comment: You don't know *what* went wrong in your `pclose` call. You don't know if the `ls` command returned with a non-zero exit code or if `pclose` itself failed. Also, if the command was not found then the `popen` call would fail so your error message is wrong.

Comment: Do you get any output from the `fgets()` / `printf()` loop?  Do you get the 'Error opening pipe!' message?  Note that you shouldn't continue to use `fp` if the `popen()` fails, and error messages should be reported on `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: I got the solution, error was in my code I have just commented the fgets then call pclose so thats why it showing error

Comment: working for me on  gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO

Answer (score 2):

`pclose()` will return `-1` on error. Otherwise, it returns the exit status. If the command was not found, `popen()` should have issued some kind of diagnostic (but, it may not have returned NULL).

If `pclose()` returns an exit status, you should check it as if it was returned by a call to `wait()`.

In comments, you mentioned the error was because you had commented out the `fgets()` loop in your test code. When you do not read out the data from the `fp`, then the called process may be blocked trying to write data to it. When you call `pclose()`, the `ls` command may then terminate due to `SIGPIPE`, since it will be trying to write to a closed pipe. You can test this by checking the error status returned from `pclose()`.

```
int status = pclose(fp);

if (status == 0) exit(0);

if (status == -1) {
    perror("pclose");
} else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    printf("terminating signal: %d", WTERMSIG(status));
} else if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    printf("exit with status: %d", WEXITSTATUS(status));
} else {
    printf("unexpected: %d", status);
}
```

In the case the `pclose()` does return an error, you may be able to get more detailed error information from `explain_pclose()` (make sure the `libexplain-dev` is installed on your system<sup>†</sup>).

> **†** The package may be named `libexplain-devel` on other Linux distros.

Comment: That's also the way to handle all the status

Comment: the actual package name is: `libexplain-dev`